# NN model ouputs one category for binary classification

Tags: matlab, neural-network, deep-learning, classification

My dataset contains labels as 0 and 1 containing 100 examples each with feature dimension 39. There are50 examples belonging to class 1 and rest 50 belonging to class 0. The graphical output shows only one output instead of two. There should be two output nodes since there are two categories. I am flabbergasted why this is happening. The following is the code. Shall be grateful for your help.

```
hiddenlayersize = 5;
net = patternnet(hiddenlayersize);
net = init(net);
netperformFcn = 'crossentropy';
[net] = train(net,x,t);
out = sim(net,x);
```

Below is the model:

[image: img]

Also, `out` is not in binary. How do I get the predicted labels in binary as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The classification outputs the results in the form of probabilities - your results are fine.
Default threshold is 0.5 for converting probabilties to 2 classes say 0 and 1.
You can fine-tune threshold - by moving up and low and further analysing the outcomes like false positives , false negatives ,precision-recall curves etc. depending upon what the objective is.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer however it is unclear why there is only one output node instead of 2 for binary classification in the picture. The picture is wrong and so the model, I guess. CAn you please answer where  I went wrong and how to change the output probabilities to 0/1 class labels.

Comment: The figure and model are both correct.
Take the output probabilities in a file say excel and mark ones > 0.5 as "1" , rest 0.
This is the default threshold for converting probs to binary values.
And then analyse the error by varying different threshold levels.
For example - after 0.5 threshold - you can try 0.4 and see if the loss decreased or increased.

Comment: Can you please clarify by explaining why do you say that there should be 1 output node and not  2 output nodes since there are two class labels but it is either 1 or 0.

Comment: Because the NN outputs probabilities for a classification problem and not discrete values (here 0 and 1) and it is out job and decision - how do we want to map these probabilities to 0 and 1 using threshold criteria.

Comment: thanks a lot! I would really appreciate if you could look into another question of mine asked here about the class imbalance problem using MLP https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58894816/class-imbalance-problem-perfweights-is-not-a-legal-parameter

Comment: Glad I could be of help.